# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

No se porque recibo ese error si jQuery es la primera librería que importo, estoy trabajando con Laravel y esto es lo que tengo en mi archivo app.js

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'

import My_Script from './script/myscript.js'
```

y en la vista wlcome.blade.php importo el script

```
<head>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</head>
```

el error lo marca en mi script en la función:

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
});
```

ya verifique que jQuery este en el archivo app.js y que este antes de mi script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La "buena práctica" para importar jQuery es importar tanto `$` como `jQuery` para poderlo usar de ambas formas, y posteriormente, hacerlo disponible para los demás scripts agregándolo a window:

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';

window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción sería que descargues la librería JQuery, la guardes en tu **public/js** y después la invoques del modo siguiente:

```
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

> Del mismo modo puedes auxiliarte del helper asset para que sea laravel
>   el que te autocomplete la ruta absoluta y cuando abras tu proyecto la
>   librería y el archivo app se carguen inmediantamente

Si no deseas hacerlo de ese modo, usa la librería misma desde un CDN como el siguiente:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Cualquiera de las opciones anteriores para asegurar que al momento de abrir tu proyecto dicho archivo se cargue de manera correcta

Comment: No es lo mismo importar un script que incluirlo desde un CDN o su copia local (aún si el resultado pueda ser el mismo), no veo por qué descargarla es lo "ideal".

Answer (score 1):

Elimina defer de app.blade tal vez necesites ponerla abajo para que cargue mejor tu web

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

así

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```