# uncaught referenceerror $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo en mi proyecto de Laravel un js que es este:

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

//activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
    'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
    'position': 'absolute'
  });
        next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
```

y encuentro este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la vista llamo al js así:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/respuestas.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" />
   <script src="/js/respuestas.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
</head>
```

Realmente no tengo mucho que inicie con Js pero no entiendo muy bien estos errores, he intentado con varias opciones pero no he llegado a un resultado, ayuda por favor!!

si añado el respectivo
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>` 
el error se va y puedo oprimir el boton de next con toda seguridad, el problema es que ahora me genera varios errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y el numero que dice 123 en realidad esta subiendo

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152162/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: Lo que no entiendo muy bien es, en donde poner el import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery; es en el js???

Comment: En la pregunta que marco como duplicada de esta indica donde ponerlo

Comment: me da este error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: En resumen: debes cargar JQuery antes de intentar usarlo, en tu caso usando el elemento `<script src="/ruta/a/jquery.min.js">` adecuado en el lugar adecuado. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solucion:

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

//activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
    'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
    'position': 'absolute'
  });
        next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### ¿Cual fue el problema?

El único problema fue que no se había cargado JQuery. Por esto fue que el navegador no reconocía el signo $. Para hacerlo tenemos varias maneras, descargando los archivos de la librería, o, como lo hice yo en la respuesta, enlazando una etiqueta `<script>` hacia la librería.

Comment: tecnicamente, el error se fue y si oprimo el boton de siguiente (next) me aparecen nuevo errores, añadire a la pregunta original

Comment: ya lo resolvi, añadi estos scripts `<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>`